# How to resolve imgly-sdk-ios missing libpods files issue?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, imgkit

i m try to create demo app using imgly sdk . after completting all steps some files following file appear red in project.
libPods-imglyKit.a , libPods.a etc another missing files you can see in attached image.

[image: missing files screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

Update the pods and open the yourproject.xcworkspace file instead of yourproject.xcodeproj.

Hope this helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Go to Terminal

step 2: Type **cd** Project Folder Path

step 3: pod update

step 4: After updating the file simply RUN

step 5: It'll work

Comment: clean your project and run again?

Comment: Still i m getting same issue